# Enable/disable button when Listview accessory type is visible/not visible

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I have a form with a firemonkey listview on it. This listview contains multiple items in it.

Using OnItemClick procedure I am trying to make a button enabled when the listview accessory type(Checkmark) is visible for each item and disabled when the accessory is not visible on all items.

I have the following code to make the accessory visible on each item when clicked.

```
Tform.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject; const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
 if AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible then
 begin
   AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible := False;
 end
 else
 begin
   AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible := True;
 end;
end;
```

I then added the following thinking it would give me what I'm after.

```
for i := 0 to AItem.Count -1 do
begin
  if (AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible) then
  begin
    Button1.Enabled := True
  end else Button1.Enabled := False;
```

For every item clicked in the listview the accessory will be visible, clicking the item again will hide the accessory. So if the accessory is visible on 1 item or more then the button will be enabled, if the accessory is removed on all items then the button should be disabled.

Comment: in second code you have `for` but always working with the same element

Comment: perhaps it should be something like `AItem[i].Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible`. plus your logic is not clear...

Comment: The code in block1 should be condensed into: `begin AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible:= not(AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible); end;`

Comment: Im sorry for not being clear. For every item clicked in the listview the accessory will be visible, clicking the items again will remove the accessory. So if the accessory is visible on 1 item or more then the button will be enabled, if the accessory is removed on all items then the button will be disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know if all subitems of an item are visible, you'll need to actually loop though them.

```
procedure Tform1.ListView1ItemClick(const Sender: TObject; const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  AllVisible: boolean;
  i: integer;
begin
  AllVisible:= (AnItem.Objects.Count > 0);
  for i:= 0 to AnItem.Objects.Count -1 do begin
    AllVisible:= AllVisible and AnItem.Objects[i].AccessoryObject.Visible;  
    //A and B will only be true if both are true.
    if not(AllVisible) then break; //jump out of loop.
  end; {for i}
  Button1.Enabled:= AllVisible;
end;
```

The problem you're having is that you're not actually looking at the individual items, you're just looking at the collective, even though that does not make sense.

Of course the real problem is that `if (AItem.Objects.AccessoryObject.Visible) then` is confusing.

`Objects` is a TListItem, which is both the item itself, and can contain a number of subitems. You are looking at the item itself. This is obviously visible, otherwise you would not be able to click it.
You need to look at the subitems one by one, not the main item itself.

I guess you got confused by the fact that `Objects` really refers to the `Object` itself. The fact that the list property is poorly documented does not help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've just tried what you have suggested, after **Objects[i].** it doesn't pickup **AccessoryObject.Visible**